# Pandas aggregate column and keep header

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have code which works but gives me data without header is there a way I can write this code so header is not removed? I know one way will be to add back header, but is there a better way?

My code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(“_data.csv",skiprows=[0], header=None)
df = df.groupby([2])[10].sum().astype(float)
```

Data:

```
A   B
1   2
1   1
2   3
2   4
```

I have data like above trying to get this result:

```
A   B
1   3
2   7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the separator (several spaces in your case) and that the header is the first row (=0, with python indexing), than groupby the column you want.

```
df = pd.read_csv("_data.csv", sep='\s*', header=0)
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  1
2  2  3
3  2  4

df = df.groupby(['A']).sum()

   B
A   
1  3
2  7
```

Comment: It is a csv file gives an error when I do: sep='\s*', also if i dont use this and use header=0, this does not remove header.

Comment: header=0 will indeed use the first row as header, you should use header=None to remove it (but the question asked how to keep it). As for the separator, it depends on your file formatting, I guess

Comment: what version of python and pandas are you using? and how is the file called?

Comment: If i keep the header sum() gives error as Column header is string.

Comment: what's the result of the read_csv in your case? maybe you should check it to understand why the following group-by doesn't work as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the function `reset_index` after the sum:

```
data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2},{'a': 1, 'b': 1},{'a': 2, 'b': 3},{'a': 2, 'b': 4}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  1
2  2  3
3  2  4

df.groupby('a').sum().reset_index()

   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  7
```